# How do i log something in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Can I use something like winston npm in the underlying .meteor/local/build/server/node_modules?

or even node-loggly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The good old [Observatory](https://atmospherejs.com/superstringsoft/observatory) has been revamped and works with Meteor 0.9+ now. Details, usage, demo app via http://observatoryjs.com

See also [pince](https://atmospherejs.com/jag/pince), a lightweight logger for Node and Meteor (client/server).

Another interesting logging package is [trail](https://github.com/tbknl/meteor-trail), which has configurable transports (console, MongoDB, custom), and can centralize logs from the server and multiple clients, and display them in an admin interface, [trail-monitor](https://github.com/tbknl/meteor-trail-monitor).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend observatory anymore. It seems to be broken with the new (Meteor 0.8) blaze rendering engine.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer: Observatory is back!

Comment: Doesn't appear to be back. I went to the observatoryjs.com and eventually left the site in confusion. You can sign up for the beta, but you get no reply. You can install it further down, but then it says 'Then sign in to your Observatory account' - which I couldn't work out how to do, so for the moment Observatory seems to be out.

Answer (score 7):

You can use winston (nodejs logging module) with meteor. And it does support several transports including, loggly, mongo and so many others.

[See my article](http://meteorhacks.com/logging-support-for-meteor.html) on how to integrate it

Comment: Nice article @arunoda, works nicely. I couldn't get winston to pick up unhandled errors though - is that something you can provide any tips on?

Comment: Thank you, you help me on all my way to meteor

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called logging however in the comments it mentions it is just temporary.
It exposes a method called Meteor._debug which basically uses console.log which works both serverside and also client side. So it might work better to use that for now.

You could however use some other logging plugin if you like, either put it in a package or use the npm's or include the javascript in your template for logging.