# Log messages being sent to/from clients in a Meteor server

Tags: events, logging, meteor, socket.io, emit

If I was curious what emit messages Meteor is sending to and receiving from clients, is there somewhere I can hook into on the server to log them?

Obviously I could watch the requests being made in the browser, but what if I wanted to log the messages on the server?

Comment: Chrome DevTools now allows you to view messages sent over a websocket. In the Network tab, inspect the request that initialised the websocket and then select the **Frames** tab next to the Headers.

Answer (score 0):

> Atmosphere has
>   [observatory](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/observatory), a
>   powerful but easy-to-use logging package.
>
> Details, usage, demo app via http://observatoryjs.com
>
> **NOTE** Observatory, while great, appears to be abandoned, and no longer works with Meteor 0.8.
>
> Another interesting logging package is
>   [trail](https://github.com/tbknl/meteor-trail), which has configurable
>   transports (console, MongoDB, custom), and can centralize logs from
>   the server and multiple clients, and display them in an admin
>   interface,
>   [trail-monitor](https://github.com/tbknl/meteor-trail-monitor).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12817907/957253

Comment: Observatory certainly looks interesting.  I wonder if parts of it can be rescued for the new Meteor.  Regarding trail, my concern is not *performing* the logging, but where to find/intercept the messages that Meteor is sending and receiving.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol used to send messages to and from Meteor clients and servers is called [DDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Data_Protocol).

I found [DDP Analyzer](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-ddp-analyzer) which acts as a proxy so it can intercept and log messages.  Introductory [blog post here](http://meteorhacks.com/debugging-meteor-packages-and-apps.html).

It does not allow WebSockets so it is not ideal on a production server, but could be useful for developer-side debugging.