# Why is Meteor preventing me from viewing my logs?

Tags: meteor

In the console, I entered (scheduler is the directory of my app):

```
C:\Meteor\scheduler>meteor logs scheduler
```

I get:

```
Sorry, that site belongs to a different user.
You are currently logged in as clayshannon.

Either have the site owner use 'meteor authorized --add' to add you as an
authorized developer for the site, or switch to an authorized account with
'meteor login'.
```

What?!? How could the site belong to a different user? And how do I change that or pin meteor's shoulders to the floor and make it cry uncle and admit that I am, indeed, the site owner?

### UPDATE

Okay, I get it now; I was successfully able to look at the logs for a public site I created; it only shows logs from today, though. Is that the default? The site has been up for several days, but all it shows is from this morning until very recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the person who deployed [scheduler.meteor.com](http://scheduler.meteor.com)? It sounds like you just want to see the logs of your local meteor app.

When you type `meteor logs scheduler`, your are asking to view the logs for [scheduler.meteor.com](http://scheduler.meteor.com). So unless you are indeed the person who deployed this website to meteor.com, it would not be very nice of them to let you view another person's logs, would it?

If what you want is the logs for your local app, they are just the ones you see after typing `meteor` to start your app:

```
C:\Meteor\scheduler>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Meteor\scheduler ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20150821-17:41:28.267(2)? This is a log entry!
```

### Otherwise...

If you did deploy [scheduler.meteor.com](http://scheduler.meteor.com), I'm afraid you did so under a different account. It happened to me recently after I mistakenly created a second account. It was quite a hassle to get it linked back to my main meteor account. Basically what I did was delete the website while logged in on the previous account:

```
$ meteor logout
Logged out.
$ meteor login
Username: DummyAccount
Password:

Logged in as dummyaccount. Thanks for being a Meteor developer!
$ meteor deploy --delete scheduler
```

And log back in with my main one to deploy it:

```
$ meteor logout
Logged out.
$ meteor login
Username: RealAccount
Password:

Logged in as realaccount. Thanks for being a Meteor developer!
$ meteor deploy scheduler
```

Comment: Yes, this is an app in its extreme early stages. Nobody has touched it by me. It is not public. It lives on my laptop, of which I am the only user.

Comment: Okay, I get it now; I was successfully able to look at the logs for a public site I created; it only shows logs from today, though. Is that the default? The site has been up for several days, but all it shows is from this morning until very recently.

Comment: Sadly, meteor does not provide any built-in tool to use logging in files out-of-the-box. Take a look at some suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166778/how-do-i-log-something-in-meteor).